# Not able to setup react native project with rn-cli. Error - 'project_name\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin' does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, create-react-native-app

I am trying to setup my first react native project with react native cli, I have used [react-native-document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native&package-manager=npm) but getting below error.

Log -

```
`info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Included build 'D:\React-native_Projects\Infovision_demo_rn_js_ts_final_projects\rn_cli\CustomApp1_new\CustomApp1\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin' does not exist.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s`
```

Environment variables -

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12
Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin;C:\Users\shubham.bhatt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin;C:\Users\shubham.bhatt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tool;C:\Gradle\gradle-7.3.1\bin;D:\React-native Projects\rn-starter-main\.expo-shared
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\shubham.bhatt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\shubham.bhatt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

How to resolve above problem?

tried to install `react-native-gradle-plugin` inside node_modules\react-native, but not resolving.